# How to remove this gap between elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the buttons in this `.input-group` justified (take up the full width available to them).  I can't seem to get it right.

#### Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.PageData.GenderID, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label"})
        </span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="input-group-btn input-group-justified">
                <label class="btn btn-default @(If(0=Model.PageData.GenderID,"active",string.empty))">
                    @Html.RadioButton("PageData.GenderID", 0, (0 = Model.PageData.GenderID), htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "gender_none"})
                    Undisclosed
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default @(If(1=Model.PageData.GenderID,"active",string.empty))">
                    @Html.RadioButton("PageData.GenderID", 1, (1 = Model.PageData.GenderID), htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "gender_female"})
                    Female
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default @(If(2=Model.PageData.GenderID,"active",string.empty))">
                    @Html.RadioButton("PageData.GenderID", 2, (2 = Model.PageData.GenderID), htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "gender_male"})
                    Male
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-for="@Html.IdFor(Function(m) m.PageData.GenderID)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in a gap as you can see in the picture.
[image: bad gap]

#### What I would like

I would like the gap to be gone and the 3 gender buttons to fill the space between the label and the question-mark button.

Alternatively, it would be ok for the gender label to grow big enough to scoot the 3 buttons over.. but simply setting the width doesn't seem right.. there is obviously some kind of disconnect between the gender button group and the end cap question-mark.

I don't know where I am going wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To the down-voter: If you need more information to diagnose the problem, tell me what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added two classes to your code and styled as follows.

**[Working Demo](http://www.bootply.com/115415)**

**CSS**

```
.form-group .dtable {
  display:table; 
  width: 100%;
  }

.tbcell {
   display:table-cell; 
    width:1%;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.
        </span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="input-group-btn input-group-justified dtable">
                <label class="btn btn-default tbcell @(If(0=Model.PageData.GenderID," active",string.empty))"="">
                    @Html.
                    Undisclosed
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default tbcell @(If(1=Model.PageData.GenderID," active",string.empty))"="">
                    @Html.
                    Female
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default tbcell @(If(2=Model.PageData.GenderID," active",string.empty))"="">
                    @Html.
                    Male
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-for="@Html.IdFor(Function(m) m.PageData.GenderID)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by adding the following CSS code within your page's head tag.

```
<style>
.input-group {width:100%; display:table !important;}
.input-group .input-group-addon {display:table-cell; width:100px;}
.input-group .btn-group  {display:table-cell;}
.input-group .btn-group .input-group-justified {display:table; width:100%;}
.input-group .btn-group .input-group-justified .btn {display:table-cell; width:30%}
.input-group .input-group-btn {display:table-cell;}
</style>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response Ayhan, however your original answer, and the first edit produced no visual results.  Your third edit messed up the other elements on the page, and did not address the gap in that block.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just fixed the code, now should be functioning properly. Tested it yet :)